# Pass data based on file contents to another screen

Tags: flutter, navigation, file-handling

When a user presses a button, I want to read data from a file. Make some decisions based on the contents of file and pass some data(depending on the file contents to a next screen).

```
void _onButtonPressed(BuildContext context) async {
    String contents = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/my_file.txt');
    List<String> lines = contents.split('\n');

    String contents2 = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/my_file_2.txt');
    List<String> lines2 = contents2.split('\n');

    int data = 9;
    //Modify data based on lines

    //Now launch the new screen
    Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => NewScreen(data: data)),
    );
  }
```

But I am getting the warning "Do not use BuildContexts across async gaps".

I tried passing the file path to next screen as a parameter and tried reading the contents in the constructor of second screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if the context is `mounted`

```dart
 if(context.mounted){
    //Now launch the new screen
    Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => NewScreen(data: data)),
    );
  }
```